# Why doesn't accumulating time of the capacitor depends on voltage?

Tags: electricity, capacitance

I've found this formula for capacitor accumulating time $T=RC$. So, if I have a capacitor and some constant resistance $R$, changing the voltage(DC, but not constant) will not influence on charging time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because while an increased voltage will cause more charge to flow to the capacitor per second (reducing the charging duration), the capacitor at the same time will store more charge (increasing the charging duration). Those two parameters happen to cancel each other out.

Think of voltage as water pressure and the capacitor as a membrane - the higher the pressure, the more the membrane can expand; analogous to the capacitor being able to store more charge.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82058/discussion-on-answer-by-steeven-why-doesnt-accumulating-time-of-the-capacitor-d).